# Find most consistent and regular rectangular places on the image for use as texture/background

Tags: opencv

I want to find a part of the image which I would use as a texture/background.

Basically I am interested in rectangles which have consistent repeating patterns, maybe without contours and colour diversity. Basically a large part which does not contain interesting content. Either uninteresting background or uninteresting foreground parts of the image.

Something like reverse contours?

Examples: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzIhN.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyKGr.jpg)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That is because problem the problem itself is quite hard to define. Basically find a range rectangle with content, that can serve as a texture. The only thing that comes to mind to me is finding places, where there are no contours.

Comment: Maybe it could be a general way for texture detection on pictures?

Comment: Your shared images have no rectangle or text ? Just messy images they re